# can someone teach me how to save data in reactjs when i click on the submit button of the PopUp.js with codes

Tags: reactjs

Problem is with the saveModal where I dont know how to give state and also change the data in the saveState({}) method. The inputs are simple where I use reactstrap for styling and that's it I have given the onClick event in the button element which is  Submit

First Problem - 
items:

```
[
      {product_category: 'Desktop', description: 'HP'},
      {product_category: 'Laptop', description: 'Dell'}
       ]
```

Second problem-

```
 saveModal = () => {

       //help me out here
    }
```

//PopUp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Container, Card, Label, CardHeader, CardBody, Form, FormGroup, Input,CardFooter, Button,InputGroupText, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon} from 'reactstrap';
import Modal from 'react-modal';


const customStyles = {
  content : {
    top                   : '50%',
    left                  : '50%',
    height                  : '50%',
    width                  : '50%',
    right                 : 'auto',
    bottom                : 'auto',
    marginRight           : '-50%',
    transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  }
};




  Modal.setAppElement('body')

class PopUp extends Component {
 constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            modalIsOpen: false,
items: [
      {product_category: 'Desktop', description: 'HP'},
      {product_category: 'Laptop', description: 'Dell'}
       ]
        };

        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
        this.changeModal = this.changeModal.bind(this);
         this.saveModal = this.saveModal.bind(this);
      }

      openModal() {
        this.setState({modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen});
      }

      closeModal() {
        this.setState({modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen});
      }

      changeModal = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.value]: e.target.value
        });
      }

      handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      saveModal = () => {

       //help me out here
    }






          render() {
            return (
              <div>
              <Container xs="12">
              <Button color="danger" onClick={ this.openModal }>+</Button>
                  <Modal
                    isOpen={ this.state.modalIsOpen }
                    onRequestClose={ this.closeModal }
                    onRequestChange= { this.changeModal }
                    onRequestSave = { this.saveModal }
                    style={customStyles}
                  >

                  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit }>
                 <Row>
                  <Col xs="12" sm="6">
                  <h2>Product Category</h2>
                  <h4>New Entry</h4>
                  </Col>
                  </Row>

                  <Row>  
                  <Col xs="12" sm="6">
                  <Label>Category</Label>
                  <Input type="text" name="product_category" id="product_category" onChange={this.changeModal }/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="12" sm="6">
                  <Label>Description</Label>
                  <Input type="textarea" row="9" col="9" name="description" id="description" onChange={this.changeModal }/>
                  </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <br/>

                   <Row>
                  <Col xs="12" sm="6">
                  <Button color="success" onClick={ this.saveModal }>Submit</Button>
                  </Col>

                  <Col xs="12" sm="6">
                  <Button color="info" onClick={ this.closeModal }>Close</Button>
                  </Col>
                  </Row>
                  </form>
              </Modal>

              </Container>
              </div>
            );
          }
      }


export default PopUp;
```

//SubCategory.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Container, Card, Label, CardHeader, CardBody, Form, FormGroup, Input,CardFooter, Button,InputGroupText, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon} from 'reactstrap';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import PopUp from './PopUp';


class SubCategory extends Component {

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
              <Container xs="12">
              <Row >
              <Col xs="12" md="9">
              <Card>
              <CardHeader>
              <h3 xs="12" >SUB CATEGORY</h3>
              </CardHeader>

              <CardBody>
                <Form>

                <FormGroup className="pr-1">
                <InputGroup >
                  <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                    <InputGroupText>
                      <i className="fa fa-cubes"></i>
                    </InputGroupText>
                  </InputGroupAddon>
                  <Input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Sub Category" name="sub_category"/>
                  </InputGroup>
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup className="pr-1">
                  <InputGroup >
                    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                      <InputGroupText>
                        <i className="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                      </InputGroupText>
                    </InputGroupAddon>
                    <Input type="select" name="parent_category" >
                  </Input>

                  <PopUp/>
                  </InputGroup>
                    </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup className="pr-1">
                <InputGroup>
                <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>
                <i className="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
                </InputGroupText>
                </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input type="textarea" rows="5" col="5" placeholder="Enter Description"name="sub_category_description"   />
                </InputGroup>
                </FormGroup>

                </Form>
              </CardBody>
              <CardFooter className="p-4">
              <Row>
                <Col xs="12"  sm="6">
                  <Button  color="success" block><span>Save</span></Button>
                </Col>
                <Col xs="12" sm="6">
                  <Button color="primary" block><span>Existing List</span></Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </CardFooter>
            </Card>
              </Col>
              </Row>
              </Container>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

export default SubCategory;
```

Comment: The submit button is not working even if i use the @codekozielt

Answer (score 0):

You already have input state present in your components state ( if I understand your code correctly)

In `saveModel` you can just add a new element to items:

```
saveModal = () => {
  const { items, product_category, description } = this.state;
  const newItems = [...items, { product_category, description }];
  this.setState({items: newItems})
}
```

Also if you have a class properties you don't need to bind them in the constructor -> these two lines are redundant:

```
this.changeModal = this.changeModal.bind(this);
this.saveModal = this.saveModal.bind(this);
```

Comment: All this is not helping me